# Unit test case for html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am not able to get the html element value in unit test using **Jasmine.**

**JavaScript code:**

```
  $scope.close = function () {
    $scope.success = false;
    $('#current, #new').val(''); // Need to test this
  };
```

**Jasmine code:**

```
  it('close method', function() {
    scope.close();
    expect($('#current')).toContain(''); //unable to get the value ->return undefined
  });
```

**Error:**

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'haystack.indexOf(needle)')

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to perform a `.toContain` test on a jQuery node collection, which is *not an Array*, so it doesn't have the `.indexOf` method your error is mentioning. If you're trying to test the value you've set using `.val()`, do this instead:

```
expect($('#current').val()).toEqual('');
```